# Pandas/Django - Cannot convert csv saved as filefield into dataframe

Tags: django, pandas

I'm building a database that stores csv files and presents them when a user selects the csv he/she wants to visualize. The problem is, whenever I open the csv file from the database the resulting dataframe is garbage

models.py

```
class Csv(models.Model):
    file_name = models.FileField(upload_to='csvs', max_length = 100)
    public = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    library = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "File id: {}".format(self.id)
```

views.py

```
def test(request):
    csv = Csv.objects.get(id = 5)
    df = pd.DataFrame(csv.file_name)
    print(df.head())
    return render(request, 'mainproj/test.html', {'df' : df.dtypes})
```

Test_Data.csv

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

The print statement in views.py returns the following output that I cannot even understand and the dataframe spits out odd values for things like columns, dtypes, ect...

[image: Code Output]

meanwhile

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('Test_Data.csv'))
print(df)
```

returns the following as expected

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the following line of code is what I needed

dataframe = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(file_obj.read().decode('utf-8')), delimiter=',')